# A weird proof that certain functions defined on intervals must be monotonic

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I saw a strange piece of reasoning in some DG book:

> Let $\phi:I\to J$ be a diffeomorphism between intervals. Then $\phi$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing because intervals are connected.

That $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism has to do with some geometric issues, and we don't have to worry about that. What concerns me a lot is that the author concludes strict monotonicity from connectedness. That's weird. I used to obtain the result by observing that $\phi$ is a continuous injection, a standard argument that can be found in many analysis books. Why would the author mention that intervals are connected? Is there any other proof that comes from connectedness? Thank you.

Comment: If the function is not striclty monotonic there is an interval whose inverse image is disconnected.

Comment: That $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism is hardly irrelevant... it's the reason you can conclude, from the connectedness of $I$ and $J$, that it must be either strictly increasing or decreasing.  (Connectedness is required.  If $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism from, say, $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ to itself, then it need not be strictly increasing or decreasing.)

Comment: Consider th derivative of $\phi$. It is continuous and never zero. Therefore (by connectedness) it must either be always positive or always negative.

Answer (score 1):

Having a continuous injection isn't enough, you also need the domain to be connected. For example, you can take the function

\begin{equation*}
f(x)  = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x & \quad x \in (0,1) \\
            -x & \quad x \in (1,2)
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}
as a counterexample.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @PrimeNumbers Thank you, but this beautiful counterexample does not yield the proof. If you were the author, what would you write down to compose a rigorous proof using connectedness? To me, that's way hard to imagine.

Comment: @Steve, I'm on my phone now so I can't type out a full answer, but I believe the essence of the proof is that if x < y < z with f(x), f(z) < f(y), then one of f(x) or f(z) is closer to f(y). Without loss of generality, f(x) < f(z) < f(y). Then, by the intermediate value theorem (which uses connectedness of the domain), there is a point c such that x < c < z (in particular, c =/= z) with f(c) = f(z), contradicting that f is injective.